# Missing of contacts from android mobile

Tags: sync, google-contacts

I am using moto g with android 5.0 version. I have turned off the auto syncing mechanism of contact. Then i added a new contact tagged by the same google account. Since the synchronization is turned off, its not saved in the google account. But where is the contact? Is it in the phone? If so, what happen if I delete the google account from the mobile? Will that newly added contact remain in the phone itself?

I have checked this condition. But once i deleted the google account the newly added contact is not in gmail account and not in phone also. Its completely disappered. Why is it so? Is there anyway to retrieve it?

Comment: Unless it's synchronized with Google contacts, once a contact is  lost, you cannot retrieve it. Make sure you sync it with Google.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do here, but anyway, here is an explanation:

When you create a contact on a Google Account, that contact is assigned to that Google Account, so that it syncs. When you remove that account, Android associates that contact with the Google Account, and removes it from the phone.